# Independent multiple scrollable containers in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter I am working on a dashboard screen where my main screen contains sidebar, top app bar and the main screen. the main screen is divided into two sections as table and form area and I want to make those two sections scrollable independently. [UI right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSoIA.png)

Right now, the `SingleChildScrollView` is able to scroll the whole page, but I only want to scroll the inner `table` and `form area`.

#### Code

```dart
class ProductsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: const SideMenu(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: backgroundColor,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              if (Responsive.isDesktop(context)) const SideMenu(),
              Expanded(
                flex: 5,
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    primary: false,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(defaultPadding),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        const TopNavBar(pageTitle: 'Products'),
                        const SizedBox(height: defaultPadding),
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: Container(
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                                child: const SingleChildScrollView(
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                  child: MyDataTable(), // returns DataTable
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            if (!Responsive.isMobile(context))
                              const SizedBox(width: defaultPadding),
                            // On Mobile means if the screen is less than 850 we don't want to show it
                            if (!Responsive.isMobile(context))
                              Expanded(
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                                  child:
                                      ProductsForm(), // returns padding>form>column>....
                                ),
                              ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I make the widgets scrollable independently?